enable admin access for a user in apache drill UI
I have enabled user authentication in drill using Custom Authenticators.
I am following guide from https://drill.apache.org/docs/creating-custom-authenticators/ 
Implemented the class with a hard coded user/password, created the jar and placed it in /jars folder.  Able to see the login screen, login is working with user/password.
here is the class implemented  -
@UserAuthenticatorTemplate(type = "myCustomAuthenticatorType")
public class MyCustomDrillUserAuthenticatorImpl implements UserAuthenticator {

    public static final String USER = "myuser";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "mypassword";
   
    @Override
    public void setup(DrillConfig drillConfig) throws DrillbitStartupException {}

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String userName, String password) throws UserAuthenticationException {
        if (!(USER.equals(userName) && PASSWORD.equals(password)) ) {
            throw new UserAuthenticationException("Authentication Failed");
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {}
}

added property to drill-override.conf
drill.exec {
        security.user.auth {
                enabled: true,
                packages += "myorg.drill.security",
                impl: "myCustomAuthenticatorType"
        }
        auth.mechanisms: ["PLAIN"]
}

and added property to drill-module.conf and put that config file inside jar file.
drill {
   classpath.scanning {
   packages += "myorg.drill.security"
  }
}

However Storage plugin options are not visible to that user in drill UI. It is treated as non-admin user.
How do I make a user admin in drill ?
I tried adding property to drill-override.conf 
security.admin.users : "myuser"
but of no use.

You'll need to assign the admin role to that user.

I am using custom authenticators, where to put admin roles properties ? I already tried what mentioned in the docs.

I believe that role assignments are unaffected by what does the authentication, custom or or not.
